Cann’t delete attribute value in Woocommerce (it was duplicated)
I have a very strange problem, I partially understand what the problem is, but I don’t know how to solve it.
I have two different attributes: SIZE and COLOR-ID. It so happened that each of them had the same value. I mean, for example, SIZE: 42 and COLOR-ID: 42. And this values had the same slug “42”.
For some time it worked correctly, but one day, apparently, something happened and all the values ​​were mixed. Some products that had the COLOR-ID 42 attribute now appear in the SIZE 42 list. I think they merged into one
I think the easiest way would be to remove these attributes and create again with new different slugs, but i cann’t delete – have error (-1) – don’t have permission for this action. In fact I am an administrator and there are no restrictions for the rules.
I don’t understand, how to delete this attribute value. Probably this should be deleted through phpmyadmin, but I’m afraid to break it.
Woocommerce 8.6.1
I tried to change the slug through phpmyadmin and saw that the slug had changed in both COLOR-ID and SIZE. I tryed to change slug “42” to “0042”, but I saw, that new slug updated both in COLOR-ID and in SIZE.

The best thing should be to access wp_terms database table via PhpMyAdmin to make the required change (if they are not custom attributes set locally on a product).
